# Does Glassfish 4.1 provides slf4j api?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish-4.1

I know that [Wildfly Aplication Server](http://wildfly.org/) provides `javax:javaee-api` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-api`, i.e. if you are working in a **Maven** project, you can do

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Provided by the container -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Provided by the container -->
  </dependency>

  <!-- The implementation -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Can I do the same with [GlassFish 4.1](https://glassfish.java.net/)? Where does it says this in the documentation? Thanks in advance for your answers.